# XSL FO Basic Links not working properly, if it is more than one line or at line breaks

Tags: pdf, xslt, hyperlink, xsl-fo

I have created a hyper link using XSL FO basic link element.

When the techname from below code is more than one line or breaking a line, the link becomes active for entire two lines. In this case, I need the link only to be active on the text not on the whole line.

Please someone give suggestion on this.

XSL code:

[Issue description screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxKHy.png)

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: This question does not meet the standards of this site.  If you want help [edit] your question and make the following corrections:  (1) Post a [mcve].  (2) Remove "URGENT!!!!" (It's obnoxious.)   (3)  Include your text as code, formatted as code, not as an image.

Comment: Please describe what is meant by "selecting entire two lines" in your picture. It is totally unclear what you mean. Also please state what XSL FO formatter you are using.

Comment: Hi Kevin,
I am using R4i binder for generating PDF from XML files.

The issue is at the line breaks. For example: consider "click here" as a link. If "click" is at end of first line and "here" is at beginning of second line, when you move cursor over that the link area is showing as both of the lines, not only to the particular words.

Comment: Then it should be considered a bug in that application. I am not clear what XSL engine they are using or if it is their own. I would contact their support.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for providing your suggestions. I will consider this as a bug in application and contact the vendor to fix this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I am not comepletely sure what you mean by active on both lines. Normally the link should be active only on the text in the link element. Could it be possible, that you did write your regular output into the link element too and just styled a part of it as link with a nested element? An alternative is to write something like this:

```
<fo:inline keep-together.within-line="1">This is the link text which should stick together in one line</fo:inline>
```

Comment: Hi Christian, Thanks for your response, My XSL code is given below:

<fo:basic-link internal-destination="{$dmRefCode}" font-family="arial" font-size="10pt" color="blue" text-decoration="underline" border=".5pt solid blue">
          <xsl:value-of select="$dmc"/></fo:basic-link>

Sometimes the value of "$dmc" is going from one line to the next line. In such cases the link becomes enabled for two lines completely.

If  the value of "$dmc" is small (within a line) it is enabling the link only to that and it is fine. The problem comes only if the line breaks.

Comment: In that case just add the attribute "keep-together.within-line" onto the fo:basic-link element and set it to any value(For inline it does not really matter so just set it to 1). This ensures that your link will get printed on one and the same line. So it will be able to break to the next line if it does not fit in the current line anymore.

Comment: Hi Christian,
I have tried adding the attribute "keep-together.within-line" for fo basic link. In some places it is creating a empty space in a line.
The requirement is to fill the line as much as possible and break the line. when the line breaks, the fo basic link needs to be partitioned into two (one in first line and other in second line and both should have same links).

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Hi Christian, This issue is due to the bug in the xsl formatting engine. The xsl codes were correct. So I will be contacting the tool vendor to fix this. Thanks for providing your suggestions on this question.